# Chartkick - charts stuck at "Loading..." [reproduced example included]

Tags: chartkick

Looked everywhere and I cannot figure out why my charts are stuck at loading...

Here is the real-world example reproduced, feel free to inspect the page and view page source, etc

https://www.starterstory.com/charts

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<%= javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick" %>` in your **layouts/application.html.erb** and then `//= link chartkick.js` into **config/manifest.js**.